# How to use pypi/regex module in App Engine?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

In my app engine application, I would like to use the alternate regular expression module `pypi/regex` instead of the default `re` module. First of all, is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

I've installed the `regex` module in my development environment and tested. It works fine in the python shell. In order to make it part of my app engine project, I copied the following files to my project folder.

```
lib\
    regex.py
    _regex_core.py
```

However, I get the following error in my application.

```
No module named lib._regex
```

copying `_regex.so` is not helping either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring):

> You can add any third-party library to your application, as long as it is implemented in "pure Python" (no C extensions) and otherwise functions in the App Engine runtime environment.

Comment: that's true for regular app engine.  but in app engine managed VM, you can install and use native libs too.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use AppEngine Managed VM.  It allows you to customize the runtime environment by using a Dockerfile and building the Docker container.

If you are new to it, I recommend check out the quick start here:  https://cloud.google.com/python/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will check that out.